# set selected values in amitava82/angular-multiselect

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

i'm new to angular and i need a multiselect box in my searchform,
i'm using for this the multiselect.js from amitava82

but a problem that i have with it is that when i want to load a savedform, I can't get selected values in it.

this is the code for the multiselectbox

```
<multiselect class="input-normal" multiple="true"
ng-model="yearlist"
options="yearList.data as yearList.data for yearList in dataYearList"
change="selected()"></multiselect>
```

to reset this i use this line of code

```
$scope.yearlist[0].checked = false;
```

this works fine

and this is the code that i try to use to set the selected values
but it doesn't works

```
$scope.yearlist=[{data:2009,checked:true},{data:2011,checked:true}];
```

how can i load this form with predefined selected values?

Comment: please link a fiddle with your code. But in general, your selected object should reference one of the items from the list, not another object with same key values. Selected value is compared by reference, not value

Comment: ok, here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/JlJuDLddOS3K7vG6KOVX

i found a way to select an item. But now i have problems with the reset of the multiselect box

Comment: Reset described here:
http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/demo-disabling-enabling

`
//reset the regionArray
      angular.forEach($scope.regionArray, function (region) {
        region.ticked = false;
      });
`

Comment: And next time it would be nice to self answer your question if you found a way and to provide the appropriate code examples/hints/links.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this also works in combination with 'amitava82/angular-multiselect', but what I do know is that if the data handling is based on a default multi select box with ng-options, you just made a common mistake.

HTML for default multi select:

```
<select multiple ng-model="yearlist" ng-options="option.data as option.data for option in dataYearList"></select>
```

If you 'dataYearList' is:

```
$scope.dataYearList = [{"data":2014},{"data":2013},{"data":2012},{"data":2011},{"data":2010},{"data":2009}] ;
```

And your yearlist is:

```
$scope.yearlist = [{"data":2012},{"data":2011}] ;
```

Your selections will not be selected in a multi select box.
But if you would change the 'yearlist' to:

```
$scope.yearlist = [2012, 2011] ;
```

Your selections will be selected.

Why?
Because the 'option.data as' refers to the option.data value which is not, for example, {"data":2012} but 2012.

Should you think to replace 'option.data as' to 'option as' because then it would be, for example,  {"data":2012}. It will not work.

For some reason the multiselect can't handle object arrays in the ng-model or it can't handle an object for the 'option.data as' in the ng-options for an initial selection... Why, I am not sure.

Hope this also helps for your issue with 'amitava82/angular-multiselect'.